# How to call a function (requiring args) with string name - Clojurescript | d3

Tags: d3.js, clojurescript

I'm trying to do some refactoring on a function (`set-attr`) that calls a function (`.attr`) on a d3 object (`node`). I want to be able to decouple the object function (`.attr`) from `set-attr`.

But I keep getting this error `Cannot read property 'each' of null`.

I'm hoping someone has experience with d3 interop in Cljs and knows of something that can work, because it works fine on regular js objects.

#### Function that works

```
(defn set-attr [node [attr settr]]
  (.attr node attr settr))
```

#### What I think should work (but gives me the error)

```
(defn set-attr [node [attr settr]]
  ((aget node "attr") attr settr))
```

#### Works fine on a regular js object

```
((aget (clj->js {:foo (fn [x y] (str "hi" x y))}) "foo" ) "ryan" "lol")
;; => "hiryanlol"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 [uses inheritance](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/a551afef97a6955d01728c1382c2da833077fb36/src/selection/index.js#L43). Thus you cannot process this object as a mere hash-table. You have to reach to its prototype to get what you want, which is usually not a good idea: this would produce rather brittle code.